# Glivenko Cantelli proof clarification

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I'm reading the proof of the Glivenko-Cantelli theorem on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glivenko%E2%80%93Cantelli_theorem#Proof. I'll appreciate it if someone clarifies what I highlighted in blue.

About the first highlight, I think it is because of the continuity of F, but I am not seeing it clearly.

The second highlight, even though it is intuitively true this holds, for the moment I don't see how to show that it is true.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 

In the case where $F$ is continuous as in the Wikipedia article, because $\lim\limits_{z\to -\infty}F(z)=0$ we can take $z'$ small enough so that $F(z')\leq \frac{1}{m}$. Because $\lim\limits_{y\to+\infty}F(y)=1$ there is a $y'$ big enough so that $F(y')>\frac{1}{m}$. By the intermediate value theorem there is a $x_{0}\leq z' \leq x_{1} \leq y' \leq x_{m}$ so that $F(x_{1})=\frac{1}{m}$. Repeat the argument by taking $y''$ so that $F(y'')>\frac{2}{m}$ and apply the intermediate value theorem again so we have $x_{1}\leq x_{2} \leq y'' \leq x_{m}$ so that $F(x_{2})=\frac{2}{m}$. And so on.

2.
For a fixed $x_{j}$ the result does follow directly from the law of large numbers, notice that $F_{n}(x_{j})$ is the average of $n$ i.i.d random variables with expected value $F(x_{j})$. Then the event $\{\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}F_{n}(x_{j})=F(x_{j})\}$ happens a.s., so $\{ \forall 0\leq j\leq m ,\; |F_{n}(x_{j})-F(x_{h})| \to 0 \}$  happens a.s.. This also implies $\max_{j}|F_{n}(x_{j})-F(x_{j})| \to 0$ a.s.. To see this, fix $\varepsilon>0$ and for every $0\leq j \leq m$ take $N_{j}$ so that $|F_{n}(x_{j})-F(x_{j})|\leq \varepsilon$ for all $n\geq N_{j}$ then take $N'=\max{N_{j}}$ so that $\max_{j}|F_{n}(x_{j})-F(x_{j})|\leq \varepsilon$ for all $n\geq N'$.